# Migrating away from apt-key adv

Tags: debian, ubuntu, gpg, migration, apt-key

I have quite some scripts that are still using the `apt-key adv` command. And I know this command is deprecated. And soon becoming unable to use.
Correct me if I'm wrong, but Debian 11 is the last Debian version supporting `apt-key`.

I also know we need to migrate to fetching the .asc file directly and put the file into the `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` folder.

How do I convert from the command below to a wget of this .asc file? Where can I find the .asc files I need? Are those .asc files even provided by Linux Mint / X2Go or other repos?

The command I use for downloading keys at the moment is:

First example: `apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com A6616109451BBBF2`
Second example: `apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com E1F958385BFE2B6E`

How do I retrieve the `.asc` (or `.gpg`) files from those repos?

Comment: Unrelated to my question. I still want to mention the following. There are key mirrors servers, instead of keyserver.ubuntu.com you could also try [keys.openpgp.org](https://keys.openpgp.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apt-key`-less equivalent to your `apt-key adv` command is

```
gpg --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com A6616109451BBBF2
gpg --export A6616109451BBBF2 | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/somenicename.gpg
```

This assumes that `gpg` is installed.

There’s no general rule regarding the availability of keyring *files*; if you have a download URL, you can use

```
sudo /usr/lib/apt/apt-helper download-file https://example.org/path/to/repokeyring.asc /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/repokeyring.asc
```

See Julian Klode’s [Migrating away from `apt-key` post](https://blog.jak-linux.org/2021/06/20/migrating-away-apt-key/) for details, and [the section in the Debian 11 release notes on obsolete components](https://www.debian.org/releases/bullseye/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#deprecated-components):

> bullseye is the final Debian release to ship **apt-key**. Keys should be managed by dropping files into `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` instead, in binary format as created by **gpg --export** with a `.gpg` extension, or ASCII armored with a `.asc` extension.

Answer (score 3):

> I also know we need to migrate to fetching the .asc file directly and put the file into the `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` folder.

### Place keyrings in `/usr/share/keyrings/`, NOT `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`.

While the `apt-key` warning message says to place keys in `trusted.gpg.d`,   Debian's ["Instructions to connect to a third-party repository"](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty) (from which I will quote extensively) **explicitly say not to do this**:

The keyrings must be stored in *"...a location only writable by root, which SHOULD be `/usr/share/keyrings/`. The key MUST NOT be placed in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` or loaded by `apt-key add`."*

### Keyrings must be in binary `.gpg` format instead of ascii-armored `.asc` format.

*"The reason why we avoid ASCII-armored files is that they can only be used by `SecureApt` in version 1.4 or later (which appeared in stretch)."*

### Each 3rd party repo needs its sources file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` which should include the `signed-by` option.

"Entries MUST be added in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory using a shortened repository name (e.g. `deriv.list`). The "Deb822" file format MAY be used instead to improve clarity for complex entries (e.g. `deriv.sources`). (See [`sources.list(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/man/buster/5/sources.list#THE_DEB_AND_DEB-SRC_TYPES:_GENERAL_FORMAT)) "

### Each 3rd Party repo should also have a prefrences file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`.

*"When a repository is added to the `sources.list.d`, a matching preferences file SHOULD be created to restrict the possible effects of the repository."*

> Where can I find the .asc files I need?

The most convenient way, assuming you already know the key ID or fingerprint, is to use GnuPG to retrieve them from a keyserver. In the case of the current Linux Mint and X2go repo signing keys:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 302F0738F465C1535761F965A6616109451BBBF2 972FD88FA0BAFB578D0476DFE1F958385BFE2B6E
```

From there you can export them to the correct binary `.gpg` file in `/usr/share/keyrings` (though I would first check to see if the keyrings are already there):

```
gpg --export 302F0738F465C1535761F965A6616109451BBBF2 | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/linuxmint-archive-keyring.gpg
gpg --export 972FD88FA0BAFB578D0476DFE1F958385BFE2B6E | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/x2go-archive-keyring.gpg
```

> Are those .asc files even provided by Linux Mint / X2Go or other repos?

They are usually provided as a .deb package to allow automatic updating to new signing keys when they are issued. You'll have to search through the package tree to find the exact location, which in the case of Linux Mint is http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/main/l/linuxmint-keyring/linuxmint-keyring_2016.05.26_all.deb.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know that I had made **so many** wrong assumptions and read wrong information in blog posts, with just a single question. I think you nailed my question, I mark your answer as accepted! Furthermore, I just noticed I'm missing a lot of pref files in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/` oopsy :). Moreover, I really hope this answer will help a lot of users in the near future. I suspect some more discussions once `apt-key` officially gets removed. I know people only start noticing the issue if its too late (=when `apt-key` is actually removed).

Comment: I have a follow-up question. I try to use this command within a Dockerfile (based on a Debian image). But the output pipes into the console: `Step 13/40 : RUN gpg --export 302F0738F465C1535761F965A6616109451BBBF2 | tee /usr/share/keyrings/linuxmint-archive-keyring.gpg
 ---> Running in 2504650c3b40
"����̩u`

Comment: To answer my own follow-up question above. For now I just pipe the output to /dev/null. I think that is fine: ` > /dev/null`.

Comment: I have a second follow-up. But I now get during the apt install commands: `W: GPG error: http://packages.x2go.org/debian bullseye InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E1F958385BFE2B6E
E: The repository 'http://packages.x2go.org/debian bullseye InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: http://packages.linuxmint.com debbie Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A6616109451BBBF2
E: The repository 'http://packages.linuxmint.com debbie Release' is not signed.`

Comment: @MelroyvandenBerg for the `public key is not available` errors, is there a `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/x2go.list` file with the line `deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/x2go-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.x2go.org/debian bullseye InRelease` or deb822 format equivalent?

Comment: Thanks. I will try this 'workaround'. Also, is Stephen right? He is saying below that the Debian docs is an opinion, it's outdated. And " wiki page is intended for repository owners and package maintainers, not for end-users"?

EDIT: I was using `apt-add-repository` command.

Comment: Well that's too bad. `apt-add-repository` command doesn't like the `[signed-by=..]` parameter.. I will create a source file manually instead, but here is the error: `Error: 'deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/x2go-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.linuxmint.com debbie main' invalid`

Comment: @MelroyvandenBerg Your linuxmint sources file's signed-by option is pointing to the wrong key (`x2go-archive-keyring.gpg`) - it should point to `linuxmint-archive-keyring.gpg`. And the Debian Wiki page is intended to document best practices for adding a 3rd party repository for both users and package maintainers. That's why it explains how to add entries to `sources.list.d` (something that is done by the user). You don't need to use `apt-add-repository` at all.